# Precompressed gzipped files cannot be served by Express possibly because wrong path

Tags: node.js, express, gzip

I have a React app with a folder structure like this:

```
├── index.html
└── app
    ├── server.js
    ├── routes.jsx
    ├── scripts
    │   ├── bundle.js
    │   ├── bundle.js.gz
    │   ├── vendor.js
    │   └── vendor.js.gz
    └── components
        └──  ...
```

I need to serve precompressed files (*.js.gz) when .js files requested but the original .js files are served, instead. This is probably because of a wrong path but I couldn't figure it out.

Here is my server.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import App from '~/routes.jsx';

const index = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = new express();
const server = new http.Server(app);

app.use('/app', express.static('app'));

app.use((request, response) => {
    const context = {};

    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={request.url} context={context}>
            <App/>
        </StaticRouter>
    );

    if (context.url) {
        response.writeHead(301, {Location: context.url});
        response.end();
    } else {
        response.write(index.replace(
            /<div id="root"><\/div>/,
            `<div id="root">${html}</div>`
        ));
        response.end();
    }
});

app.get('*.js', function (request, response, next) {
    console.log('js requested');
    request.url = request.url + '.gz';
    response.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    next();
});

server.listen(PORT);
console.log(`\nApplication available at localhost:${PORT}\n`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware in Express is always invoked in the order you added them. So to load `*.js.gz` file, you need to move the middleware above the 
`express.static` middleware.

```
//...
//load this middleware first
app.get('*.js', function (request, response, next) {
    console.log('js requested');
    request.url = request.url + '.gz';
    response.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    next();
});
//then load the express.static middleware
app.use('/app', express.static('app'));
//...
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I was getting really mad about it.

Comment: Files are served properly, so your suggestion works but there is another problem. I am getting 304 Not Modified error. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Okay, I solved it. Forget about my monologue here :)